# smach-viewer install

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Could somebody tell me how could I install the smash-viewer package in ROS-Hydro, please.
I though that the package should be already in the las distribution but I have just installed Hydro full desktop and it isn't there.
I also tried apt-get install ros-hydro-smach-viewer and nothing

Thanks in advance,
Roberto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139656/smach-viewer-install/) by [rober](https://answers.ros.org/users/13306/rober/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I reinstalled everything from the scratch and it works just doing:

sudo apt-get install smach-viewer

I guess I had made something wrong with the repositories.

Thank you in any case for the answer.

---

Originally posted by [rober](https://answers.ros.org/users/13306/rober/) with karma: 16 on 2014-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0